# Implementar Google Ads en una App Móvil Android

Tags: java, android-studio, xml, google-adsense

tengo una pregunta y espero me puedan hacer el favor de solucionar si alguien sabe.
Estoy implementando en mi app móvil Google ads.
Este es mi gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.desarrollador.android.globalapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
}
```

En mi manifest, añadí esta etiqueta

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="ca-app-pub-4837289252712334~8297488426" />
```

Este es mi XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Y este es mi MainActivity donde estoy llamando y asignando Google ADS:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-4837289252712334~8297488426");
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4837289252712334/3053734757");
```

Me aparece el banner de publicidad, pero me aparece en blanco, no me aparece ni una publicidad de prueba.
Otra problema que tengo es que cuando creo la cuenta me dan dos Token (ID), pero según yo, debo colocar el primero en el manifest y el segundo en el MainActivity, pero no estoy seguro, además, aparece lo que comento, no sé si alguien me pueda ayudar.

Coloqué toda la información necesaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` , recuerda que debes permitir a tu aplicación conexión a internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Revisa en tu `LogCat`, un mensaje similar a este se debe desplegar, el cual contiene el id del dispositivo de prueba a configurar para emular la carga de anuncios:

> Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test
>   ads on this device.

---

Básicamente el problema que comentas se debe a que estas creando una vista con el anuncio pero esta no se esta agregando en ninguna parte, por lo tanto esto es incorrecto:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
```

en su lugar debes obtener la referencia de la vista que ya estas incluyendo en tu layout .xml, de esta forma:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

también esto no es necesario :

```
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4837289252712334/3053734757");
```

ya que estas propiedades las estas definiendo en la vista dentro del layout (`ads:adSize` y `ads:adUnitId`):

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Este sería el código correcto:

```
   // Inicializacion
   MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");    

   // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
   AdView adView= (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
             .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
             .addTestDevice("<id desplegado en LogCat>")
             .build();
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

[image: Jorgesys admob elenasys]

Te comparto este proyecto de ejemplo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android_AdMob